# Use variable to call data column in dataset d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hey guys sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm really noob at `Javascript / d3.js`. So basically I have a `.csv` file with lots of countries and their amount of military forces for each year looking like this:

```
year,country1,country2,country3,...

1989,192129,129312,12391,...

1990,192913,123131,12331,...

1991,123112,123123,12313,...
```

I have made a line graph with year on the x-axis and the forces of a country on the y-axis using

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
if (error) throw error;
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.Year = parseTime(d.Year);
  d.NLD = +d.NLD;
});

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Year; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.NLD; })]);
```

(NLD being the country code)along with other stuff taken from https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/257c360b3650b9f0a52dd8257d7a2d73

This works fine but now my question is can I make a variable that you can place instead of the NLD so that you can easily change between them like

```
var country = "NLD";
```

and then place that variable so that the code looks like this

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
if (error) throw error;
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.Year = parseTime(d.Year);
  d.country = +d.country;
});

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Year; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.country; })]);
```

Putting it in between curly brackets like `d.{country}` doesn't work for me either.

Sorry if this question has been asked before, but I don't know how to ask this and I have searched and couldn't find anything.

Comment: instead of `d.country` use `d[country]`

Comment: Omg the solution is so simple haha I've tried d.{country} and d.[country] before but they didn't work but I'd never thought of d[country]. Thans a lot!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) but basically property accessors take one of two forms, a dot accessor as in `d.country` or a square bracket accessor as in `d['NLD']`. Using the dot notation, whatever comes after the dot must be a valid property name. In your code `d.country` is literally looking for the value of the `country` property on the object `d`. In this case what you should do is use the square bracket accessor. In the square bracket accessor, whatever you put in square brackets, what it evaluates to becomes the property that is accessed. So your code would look like this

```
var country = 'NLD'
...
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d[country]; })]);
```

This is equivalent to writing `d['NLD']` which is equivalent to writing `d.NLD`